# How to check if memcached is running and start it if not from python?

Tags: python, memcached

I'm developing a web application using python and memcached.

First I want to start memcached from my python program, and if I'm right `subprocess.Popen(["memcached"]);` will do it. What really bothers me is how to check if memcached is already running in the background.

I want something like

```
if check_memcached():
    start_memcached();
```

The `check_memcached()` function should return true if memcached is not already running. Anybody got any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to check may depend on your platform.  Here's some methods you could try:

- Try to connect to the memcached server.  If a connection fails, assume that the server is not running.
- If you expect memcached to be running locally, look for a PID file.  On Debian this is usually located at `/var/run/memcached.pid` and contains the process id of the running memcached daemon.  To be extra sure you could read the PID contained in the file and verify that a process with this PID is still running.
- Use the `subprocess` module to run a command which can directly check for a locally running daemon.  eg. Run the command `pidof memcached` using `subprocess` and check the return code.

Comment: If you are running ubuntu a `service memcached status` will give you the result.